# How to calculate using derivative definition

Tags: derivatives, radicals

I am trying to find the derivative of $f$ at $x=1$ when $y=\sqrt{3x+1}$ using only the following derivative definition:

$$f^\prime(1)=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)−f(1)}{x−1}$$

I think I need to get rid of the radical first, but I simply cannot find the right way. I am relearning math after many years, so please bear with me.

Comment: I think you may have mixed up [how to write equations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) with how to write code, but I've fixed that now.

Comment: Use the conjugate expression :  $f(x)-f(1)=\dfrac{f(x)^2-f(1)^2}{f(x)+f(1)}$.

Comment: @ J.G. Yes, you're right. I need to learn the difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(\sqrt{3x+1}-2)(\sqrt{3x+1}+2)=3(x-1)$,$$f^\prime(1)=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt{3x+1}-2}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{3}{\sqrt{3x+1}+2}=\frac34.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\sqrt b-\sqrt a=\frac{b-a}{\sqrt b+\sqrt a}$.